# js how to pass long parameter inline?

Tags: javascript

I have some JS code which dynamically output HTML code to Datatable cell as following.

```
$('td:eq(7)', nRow).html("<a onclick='showOrder("+orderId.toString()+");' style='cursor:hand;color:blue'>" +orderNo + "</a>");

function showOrder(id) {
      var Window = window.open( orderURL+"/order?orderId=" + id, '_blank');
}
```

showOrder is just a function to call when the Datatable cell is clicked. The problem here is orderId is something like 6494933473411334145 which exceed the range of JS long type. The window showOrder actually open is of the wrong id like  6494933473411330000. I had tried many way to solve the problem but the only way worked is as the following:

```
$('td:eq(7)', nRow).html("<a href='"+orderURL+"/order/toTag?orderId=" + orderId +"' target='_blank' style='cursor:hand;color:blue'>" +orderNo + "</a>");
```

Instead of calling a function, encode the id inside html can solve the problem. Does anyone know how to solve this problem using the function call way?

Answer (score 0):

My coworker find a solution simply as following:

```
var id  = "'"+orderId+"'"
showOrder(id) {
  var Window = window.open( orderURL+"/order?orderId=" + id, '_blank');
}
```

It seems orderId will be treated as Long and toString will not work in this case. Only by converting the Long to String before using it can avoid the problem.